# How to make backups of the database in Magento 2.4 in admin?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.5

How to make backups of the database from the admin (Back) in Magento 2.3 or Magento 2.4?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**In case you don't have SSH access.** Backup in Admin to Magento 2.3 and 2.4

Here is how you do it:

**1. Activate Backup:**

- Click in STORES
- Go to configuration / ADVANCE / System
- Go to Backup Settings / Select Enable Backup -> Yes
- Click *Save Config*
- Click in top **Cache Management**
- Click in Flush Magento Cache.

One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Configuration, Page Cache. Please go to **Cache Management** and refresh cache types.

**2. Generate Backup Database:**

- Go to SYSTEM / TOOLS / Backups /
- Click in Database Bakcup
- Write name in Backup Name (no spaces)
- Not Check Maintenance mode

Download database, click in zip.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Don't.**

I mean, you can... and it *technically* works, but It's glacially slow. Backing up your DB is significantly faster using something like `mysqldump`. Adobe's own [documentation](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/tutorials/backup.html) recommend *not* using it. On top of that the functionality is deprecated and they are planning on removing it.

Save yourself time, headaches and *most importantly*... **downtime**! Find a better solution.

Comment: Craig, In case you don't have SSH access, how can you create a backup?

Comment: If you don't have SSH access then I suspect you will still have either: A managed hosting provider (In which case either raise a ticket or use their admin panel, assuming they have one), OR something like cPanel which provides a UI for creating a backup.

It should be noted that when operating a Magento store having SSH access is critical for a number of maintenance tasks, such as accessing logs or deploying new releases and security updates.

Comment: It should be noted that there are types of roles in a project with the frontend, which can get a quick backup of the database from the admin(back). For example, in my case, I am working with an on-demand environment that I do not have access to the VPN. In addition, the configuration can take time.

Comment: Making a backup of the database from admin is not the most appropriate, but having a copy of the database can solve us.

Comment: Re: different roles thats a fair point and I completely agree, anything we can do to improve the dev experience is good. If this was being done on a staging environment I think that would be acceptable, however I would say this tool should NEVER be used on prod, I think the only time I have seen it run to completion is on a fresh install. I think perhaps this module should be one that gets automatically hidden in production mode, similar to the "Develop" menu.

Comment: I agree with you, it should not be used in production, thank you very much.